# Selected Valued in JSF PRIMEFACES not been displayed

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i am using datalist of primefaces jsf . I am just populating data from arraylist and show in datalist and also using dialog box for detailed view ,but problem this with selected values   dialog box does not show them.here is the code 
UI Class :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:dataList value="#{tableBean.applicantlist}" var="applicant"
                id="applicants" paginator="true" rows="5"
                paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" type="none">


                <f:facet name="header">  
                Applicants 
            </f:facet>


                <h:outputText value="#{applicant.jobtitle}, #{applicant.useremail}"
                    style="margin-left:10px" />

                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form:appDetail"
                    oncomplete="appDialog.show()" title="View Detail">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{applicant}"
                        target="#{tableBean.selectedApplicant}" />
                </p:commandButton>

            </p:dataList>


            <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="appDialog" modal="true"
                showEffect="fade">
                <p:outputPanel id="appDetail" style="text-align:center;"
                    layout="block">



                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <h:outputLabel for="modelNo" value="Model No: " />
                        <h:outputText id="modelNo"
                            value="#{tableBean.selectedApplicant.useremail}" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>

        </h:form>


    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

here is table bean :

```
package com.DTO;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TableBean implements Serializable {

    private List<InterViewDto> applicantlist;
    private InterViewDto selectedApplicant;

    public List<InterViewDto> getApplicantlist() {
        return applicantlist;
    }

    public void setApplicantlist(List<InterViewDto> applicantlist) {
        this.applicantlist = applicantlist;
    }

    public InterViewDto getSelectedApplicant() {
        return selectedApplicant;
    }

    public void setSelectedApplicant(InterViewDto selectedApplicant) {
        this.selectedApplicant = selectedApplicant;
    }

    public TableBean() {
        getSelectedApplicant();
        applicantlist = new ArrayList<InterViewDto>();
        InterViewDto p1 = new InterViewDto();
        p1.setJobtitle("junaid");
        p1.setUseremail("email@hotmail.com");
        applicantlist.add(p1);

    }

}

Here is DTO Class:

package com.DTO;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;



@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class InterViewDto {

    String useremail,jobtitle;
    Date date;
    public String getUseremail() {
        return useremail;
    }

    public InterViewDto(){

    }
    public void setUseremail(String useremail) {
        this.useremail = useremail;
    }
    public String getJobtitle() {
        return jobtitle;
    }
    public void setJobtitle(String jobtitle) {
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }





}
```

Comment: Its not showing data in Dialog box

Answer (score 0):

`p:commandButton` and `p:commandLink` actions does not work inside data table, data list or any component which is populated by a List in backing bean if the list is not enclosed by `p:column`.

Enclose each item which is shown in table by `p:column`.

```
<p:dataList value="#{tableBean.applicantlist}" var="applicant"
                id="applicants" paginator="true" rows="5"
                paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" type="none">


              <p:column > 
                <h:outputText value="#{applicant.jobtitle}, #{applicant.useremail}"
                    style="margin-left:10px" />

 </p:column > 
 <p:column > 
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" update=":form:appDetail"
                    oncomplete="appDialog.show()" title="View Detail">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{applicant}"
                        target="#{tableBean.selectedApplicant}" />
                </p:commandButton>

 </p:column > 
            </p:dataList>
```